# Chrome Extension connect Chrome Debugger and take full screenshot

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to take a full size screenshot in the active tab using a chrome plugin.

I know there is a function called *chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab ()*, but this does not help to  get a full page screenshot.

I know we can get a full page screenshot from chrome (devtools > ctrl+shift+p > Capture full size screenshot). I want to take a screenshot using this feature or a different feature.

With the code I have given below, I can take full page screenshots on a linux machine for my purpose. But when I run the plugin on a windows machine, I get an image like this:
[image]

this is my code. It may be more helpful to start reading from the bottom:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(attachToDebugger);

function clearDeviceMetricsOverride(tabId, base_64_data) {
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
    {
      tabId: tabId,
    },
    "Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride",
    function () {
      postData(base_64_data, tabId);
    }
  );
}


function captureScreenshot(tabId) {
  console.log(`{page}: captureScreenshot: status=aboutTo, tabId=${tabId}`);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
    { tabId: tabId },
    "Page.captureScreenshot",
    {
      format: "jpeg",
      quality: 60,
      fromSurface: false,
    },
    (response) => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(`{back}: captureScreenshot: status=failed, tabId=${tabId}`);
      } else {
        var dataType = typeof response.data;
        console.log(
          `{back}: captureScreenshot: status=success, tabId=${tabId}, dataType=${dataType}`
        );
        let base_64_data = "data:image/jpg;base64," + response.data;
        setTimeout(() => {
          clearDeviceMetricsOverride(tabId, base_64_data);
        }, 500);
      }
    }
  );

  console.log(`{page}: captureScreenshot: status=commandSent, tabId=${tabId}`);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function setDeviceMetricsOverride(tabId, height, width) {
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
    {
      tabId: tabId,
    },
    "Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride",
    { height: height, width: width, deviceScaleFactor: 1, mobile: false },
    function () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        captureScreenshot(tabId);
      }, 500);
    }
  );
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

function getLayoutMetrics(tabId) {
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
    {
      tabId: tabId,
    },
    "Page.getLayoutMetrics",
    {},
    function (object) {
      console.log("---- get layout w: " + object.contentSize.width);
      console.log("---- get layout h: " + object.contentSize.height);
      const { height, width } = object.contentSize;
      setDeviceMetricsOverride(tabId, height, width);
    }
  );
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

function setColorlessBackground(tabId) {
  console.log(`{back}: setColorlessBackground: status=aboutTo, tabId=${tabId}`);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
    { tabId: tabId },
    "Emulation.setDefaultBackgroundColorOverride",
    { color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0 } },
    function () {
      console.log(
        `{back}: setColorlessBackground: status=enabled, tabId=${tabId}`
      );
      getLayoutMetrics(tabId);
    }
  );

  console.log(
    `{back}: setColorlessBackground: status=commandSent, tabId=${tabId}`
  );
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

function enableDTPage(tabId) {
  console.log(`{back}: enableDTPage: status=aboutTo, tabId=${tabId}`);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId }, "Page.enable", {}, function () {
    console.log(`{back}: enableDTPage: status=enabled, tabId=${tabId}`);
    setColorlessBackground(tabId);
  });

  console.log(`{back}: enableDTPage: status=commandSent, tabId=${tabId}`);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

function attachToDebugger(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  try {
    if (tab.status == "complete") {
      chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, "1.0", () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.log(
            `{back}: debugger attach failed: error=${chrome.runtime.lastError.message}`
          );
        } else {
          console.log(`{back}: debugger attach success: tabId=${tabId}`);
          enableDTPage(tabId);
        }
      });
    }
  } catch {}
}
```

Comment: Since it works correctly in Linux the only explanation is that it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: When I view the codes in Puppeteer, I see that it takes a screenshot in the same way as me (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/46115f91829a1bb7da46b51c604ca62ba0bce7e3/lib/Page.js#L484) Taking screenshots using puppeteer on a windows machine is fine. so I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: There are no other explanations if the same command in an extension produces the correct result in Linux but not in Windows.

Comment: Hey! Any success on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the code I have given below, I can take full page screenshots on a linux machine for my purpose.

Not sure how Linux differentiates the surface and the view (if your code works), but for Windows you have to change this:

```
"Page.captureScreenshot",
    {
      format: "jpeg",
      quality: 60,
      fromSurface: false,
```

To this:

```
"Page.captureScreenshot",
    {
      format: "jpeg",
      quality: 60,
      fromSurface: true,
```

Your code will produce full page screenshot with this fix. I'm not sure you changed the `fromSurface` property value from the example you took this code from, since in the docs they say that this property will force the API to make a screenshot within the view, if set to `false`, which makes sense for result to become cropped.